# Разрешить удаленный доступ к БД Mongo

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, config

На сервере c Windows развернута БД Mongo со стандартным портом 27017. По умолчанию  БД настроена на локальный доступ, т.е. на самой машине с БД я могу к ней подключаться, с другого сервера нет. 
Нашел информацию по редактированию config файла (.cfg).
Прописывал в строке bindIp: несколько вариантов:

1. bindIp: 127.0.0.1 - стандартный
2. bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0
3. bindIp: 0.0.0.0
4. bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 10.8.153.99

После изменений заново запускал БД, но доступ все также сохранялся только локальный. Подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Comment: А что насчет фаервола? Открыт ли внешний доступ к порту 27017?

Comment: Сейчас смотрел в Брандмауэр - правило для входящих подключений на 27017 есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо при запуске Mongo прописывать явно путь к config файлу в консоли. 
Команда: C:\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe --config C:\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg